# Setting an image in specifically the left side of a button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'd like to create an android button that has an image on the left hand side.  Currently the only way I know to set images inside buttons is by using the android:background property and setting that to an image, but doing so stretches the image.  I'd like to avoid stretching the image and make sure it stay at its normal size on the left of the button.

How would I modify the following code to achieve my goal?

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:focusable="true" 
           android:background="@drawable/buttonBack">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

[image]

```
<!-- For Image to the left of the text use android:drawableLeft tag -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/down_arrow"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/leftimage" />
        <!-- For Image to the Right of the text use android:drawableRight tag -->

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/down_arrow"
            android:text="@string/righttimage" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That works if the image it ths correct size... what if you need to scale the image (say it's very large) and apply it to the button? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
```